# Zabbix trigger checking a file in a certain time period

Tags: logging, monitoring, zabbix

I need to set up a zabbix trigger that will check a log file from 20h to 22h each day, and look for a certain pattern.
In case there is no data in these two hours, an alert should be fired.
The syntax of the trigger I configured is like this:

---

> "{item.time(0)}>200000&{item.time(0)}<220000&{item.nodata(7800)}=1"

---

This Trigger works fine. However, I've noticed two bad sides:

1. If the file has not been received at 20h, it fires an alert, but I
   need it to fire it, only if the file is still not received at 22h.
2. Even if the file has not been received until 22h, it sends an OK
   message once it is 22h00m30s (once it is no longer in the specified
   time period)

I was thinking of reducing the time period to 30min (from 21h30 to 22h): this resolved the first issue, but I still have troubles with the second one.

One last thing. If I reduce the time period to 30min but kept the agent looking for data for 7800s (nodata(7800)), will it check logs entries that have been written before 21h30?

Please, if you have any suggestion, I will be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

It might be better off to use a cronjob zabbix_trapper to send the data.

On the Zabbix server, you would create a trapper check with something like "file.summary". On the host, you would create a script that checks the file at the appropriate time. It might like look this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

if [[ `pattern check` == "0" ]]
then
  /usr/bin/zabbix_sender -z zabbix-server.com -s `hostname` -k file.summary -o 1
else
  /usr/bin/zabbix_sender -z zabbix-server.com -s `hostname` -k file.summary -o 0
fi
```

You should set your alarm to trigger with a value of != 0.